# cant we access Mysql server without setting class path to it in environment variables in windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, classpath

I have installed the `mysql` server in `windows`. do i need to set the `class path` in environmental variables, without which can't i access the mysql server, using the `command prompt` of `windows` or connecting to it from any `other system`? what is the purpose of `setting` the `class` path? i `installed` `ms sequel` server, that is also a database server. To this `ms sequel` server i did not set any class path i was able to connect to it without any issues.

Comment: mysql has no classpath. are you talking about Java? mysql couldn't care less how you're accessing it. you access it from anything that "talks" the mysql API. whether that's from java, c#, php, telnetting to port 3306 and typing in the commands manually, etc.. is irrelevant.

Comment: no i just installed Mysql server. if any software lets say bio-metric software which is istalled on the machine, wants to push some data to mysql server, can it push? and my app is a ROR application from this app, i want to connect to mysql server. can i connect to mysql server in both these cases without setting the class path to it?

Comment: ruby has no classpath either. just load up whatever mysql interface library you want in ruby and go...